# Correct way of getting a right implementation of the same interface

Tags: c#, interface, asp.net-core-2.0

Keep in mind that I'm not looking to add additional dependencies if I don't have to. Also, most of the ideas are already from here (stackoverflow.com) that I found while searching for a solution.

Lets say I have an IPrinterRepository interface for which I have multiple different implementations.

For example 
EpsonRepository implemnets IPrinterRepository as do CanonRepository, HPRepository, and many others

So now I registerd my services in **ConfigurationServices** like this

```
services.AddTransient<EpsonRepository>();
services.AddTransient<HPRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<IPrinterRepositoryResolver, PrinterRepositoryResolver>();
```

**- V1 -**

For now I have been saving a PRINTER_CODE in my DB for every active printer some specific user has activated. PrinterCode is a class of const strings.

PrinterRepositoryResolver handles the selection of the right implementation. So there is a method that does just that using switch statement.

```
public IPrinterRepository GetRepository(string key)
{   
    switch (key)
    {
        case PrinterCode.Epson:
            return (IPrinterRepository)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(EpsonRepository));
        case PrinterCode.HP:
            return (IPrinterRepository)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(HPRepository));
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Sevice not implemented or not supported any more!");
    }
}
```

**- V2 -**

Or maybe I can select the right implementation by type so I don't have to use PRINTER_CODE or maintain the switch statement. Example

Instead of PRINTER_CODE saving a fullName of implementation in DB as a string and using that to select the right implementation later when needed.

```
public IPrinterRepository GetRepository(string ImplementationName)
{
    var repoType= Type.GetType(ImplementationName);
    return (IPrinterRepository)_serviceProvider.GetService(repoType);
}
```

This all works in my dev-environment, but I don't know if its OK.

Personally, I don't like the switch because someone will have to maintain the PrinterCodes and the switch every time a new printer implementation is added.

But also saving a long string with namespace as a key for selection is somehow ugly and I feel there may be more downsides that I am not aware. Are there some adjustment or better ideas so I can do this the right way.

Comment: Have you considered exposing a `.Key` property on `IPrinterRepository`? Then there's no switch statement just a quick scan of the resolved `IEnumerable<IPrinterRepository>` objects to find the one that has the matching name? Or put them in a dictionary on startup if you have a huge number of them.

Comment: You could also look at using Autofac which supports metadata-driven resolving of dependencies, see http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#metadata-interrogation-meta-b-meta-b-x

Comment: Will skip this time on Autofac because don't want to add more dependencies than needed. I am leaning more to your suggestion with the key property but will explore all options. Since @Ian_Mercer didn't provide answer I can mark as solution I'll go with armenm's solution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the slightly modified V1 way:

The object obtaining boilerplate is avoided and the object type is not tightly coupled to it's name like in the V2 case.

```
public IPrinterRepository GetRepository(string name)
{
    if (!_PrinterTypes.TryGetValue(name, out var type))
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Sevice not implemented or not supported any more!");

    return _serviceProvider.GetService(type);
}

static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _PrinterTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    [PrinterCode.Epson] = typeof(EpsonRepository),
    [PrinterCode.HP] = typeof(HPRepository)
};
```